# How do you efficiently load 10 million rows, run a function on them and then write some changes back to the db

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Say you have 10 million rows in a db table represented by a django model. How do you efficiently load all of these, run a function on them and then write some changes back to the db.

I am trying to find the correct course of action when dealing with such a problem

Comment: What is the function? Provide more details. The answer will be different if you need to add 1 to some field and different if you need to do something complicated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Table with Million of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051481/django-table-with-million-of-rows)

Comment: Updating in batches can be done efficiently as mentioned [here.](https://blog.labdigital.nl/working-with-huge-data-sets-in-django-169453bca049)

Comment: That is a too broad question. To make it more focused, could you please clarify some details? For instance, what type of function do you intend to apply? Will it be a one-time execution or will it be executed multiple times? Is it going to be part of an API or is it more of a backfilling task? Providing this information will help to better understand your needs and get an accurate response.